# Update Column increment by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which is composed of numbers 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9….

Please advise on the SQL Stored Procedure on how to update this column starting from 1 and so on `where ORDERBY date_column(date)`.

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.) Tag the dbms you're using. Show us your current code attempt.

Comment: Depending on your DBMS this might be more or less simple, but why do you think you need it? Do you want to start renumbering whenever a row is deleted?

Comment: Please tell us the dabatase management system you are using. It is SQL Server or MySQL for example? SQL is just the query language.

Comment: SQL Server is the DB im using.

Comment: UPDATE TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS
SET PRIORITY_CD = (PRIORITY_CD + 1) is not applicable since what if priority_cd value is 1 so it will be updated into "2". I should start at 1.

Comment: What is the number sequence you want? Please define carefully (gap of two then one then three isn't enough to infer the required pattern).

Comment: I already got the logic but i got an error. ORDER BY is not recognized in my update statement

Comment: The question is rather why you want to do this? There's usually no need to renumber items (and fill in gaps.) Keep the values you have!

Comment: i need to have a 1, 2 ,3 values as requirement.

Comment: What `update` statement do you get an error in? You need to include the code that is not working *in the question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this. Please check the order by direction and what to do if 2 rows hold the same date value (you can add additional expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause inside the `OVER`).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ResetNumber
AS
BEGIN

    ;WITH Ranking AS
    (
        SELECT
            T.ColumnWhichHoldsTheValue,
            Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.date_column ASC) -- Please see if it should be ASC or DESC
        FROM
            YourTable AS T
    )
    UPDATE T SET
        ColumnWhichHoldsTheValue = T.Ranking
    FROM
        Ranking AS T

END
```

Comment: Thanks Ezequiel, This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.